# Choosing a random entry from a JSON string

Tags: c#, json, parsing, microsoft-metro

My code retrieves a huge list of items and then displays them. What I want to do instead is retrieve the list then randomly choose a entry and display only that, how would I go about it? This is what i have tried:

```
using (var wc = new HttpClient())
            {

                string json = await wc.GetStringAsync(trendingURL);
                dynamic obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);
                foreach (var item in obj)
                {
                    string Name = item.title;
                }
            }
```

So in this scenario, is there an alternative from doing a foreach statement? Can I somehow get the count of entries and choose number 50 and display that?

Comment: cast `obj` to an enumeration and call the `Count` extension method.  Then use http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.random.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Random rnd = new Random(); //Create this random class only once.

JArray obj = (JArray)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);
dynamic item = obj[rnd.Next(0, obj.Count)];
Console.WriteLine(item.title);
```